# React Native Screen refresh from nested component screen

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have a screen, PDP, that screen contains a component, TopNews. I want TopNews onclick to redraw PDP (it passes in an Article ID which the PDP uses to retrieve the article). The diagram below shows the flow

[image]

The code I have to support this inside TopNews is;

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Pdp', {articleid: item.id})}>
```

The challenge is the TouchableOpacity event triggers, but the page doesn't refresh the PDP. I don't want to refresh only the PDP as I may include the TopNews component in other screens outside of the PDP, its just in this case its inside of the screen it needs to call.

Answer (score 0):

There are more then one way to do it.

You can create a state for the article id and allow the `TopNews` to set this state:

```
const PDP = () => {
  const [ id, setId ] = React.useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      <ArticleComponent articleId={id} />
      <TopNews idSetter={setId} />
    </div>
  );
}

const ArticleComponent = ({ articleId }) => {
  return /* something that renders the article by the id */ ;
}

const TopNews = ({ idSetter }) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => {
        idSetter(item.id);
        navigation.navigate('Pdp')
      }}>
  );
}
```

Another more elegant way, is to use [react contexts](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/context.html). You can create a context provider in the PDP component and change the context data in any PDP's children component.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, instead of using navigation.navigate, use navigation.push instead;

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.push('Pdp', {articleid: item.id})}>
```

This works perfectly :)